# Datatables js Format not getting applied properly

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, datatables

I am trying to apply [Datatables js](http://www.datatables.net/) on asp.net grid view. The issue is i have large number of columns. when the number of columns are large it doesn't render the css properly. Also the arrows showing sorting are not visible on headers.

Please take a look at the screenshot.
[image]

Please suggest me the solution for this to render the controls in place for paging and searching.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover"
            GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPreRender="gvReport_PreRender" Width="100%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a class="fancybox" href='<%#string.Format("/Images/PRODUCT/{0}",Eval("ProdImagePath")) %>'>
                            <img src="Content/images/Image.png" height="20" width="20" /></a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img src="Content/images/View.png" style="cursor: pointer;"
                            onclick="OpenModalPopUp('<%#string.Format("/Images/PAGE/{0}",Eval("PageImagePath")) %>','<%#string.Format("/Images/PRODUCT/{0}",Eval("ProdImagePath")) %>')" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a class="fancybox" href='<%#string.Format("/Images/PAGE/{0}",Eval("PageImagePath")) %>'>
                            <img src="Content/images/Page.png" /></a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Account" DataField="account" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Period" DataField="period" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="End Date" DataField="end_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Start Date" DataField="start_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Days" DataField="number_of_days" />

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Collection" DataField="collection_type" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Week" DataField="weeks" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="Category" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Market" DataField="Market" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Brand" DataField="Brand" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Size" DataField="Size" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pur_Qty" DataField="Pur_Qty" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Product_Description" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sale Price" DataField="Sale_Price" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reg. Price (Low)" DataField="Reg_Price_Low" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Unit Price Sale" DataField="Unit_Price_Sale" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NOR Price" DataField="NOR_Price" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="% OFF" DataField="percente_off" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reg. Price High" DataField="Reg_Price_High" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Retail Coupon" DataField="Retail_Coupon" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Mfr Coupon" DataField="Mfr_Coupon" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Limit" DataField="Limit" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Events" DataField="Events" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Save Up To" DataField="Save_Up_To" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ad Type" DataField="Ad_Type" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Theme" DataField="Theme" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Offer Desc" DataField="Offer_Description" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Page Position" DataField="Page_Position" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Promotions" DataField="Promotions" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Manufacturer" DataField="Manufacturer" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Retailer Points" DataField="Retailer_Points" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Week Month" DataField="Week_Month" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Master Brand" DataField="Master_Brand" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Year" DataField="Year" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Brand_Family" DataField="Brand_Family" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Region" DataField="Region" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Size Segmentation" DataField="Size_Segmentation" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Data table js :

```
  $("#gvReport").DataTable({ "iDisplayLength": 100, "scrollX": true });
```

Comment: Inspect it take a class name apply class with your new properties done!

Comment: but this things should be done automatically right ? and it is working fine for the small number of columns.

Comment: can you add one demo?

Comment: how to do that ? i have posted my code here. You can see here http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: use jsfiddle paste your data and then paste a link here

Comment: `should be done automatically` ...  you have to make adjustments all the time to make things fit your needs, why would this be any different

Comment: @Justcode thanks for your guidance. I have posted the answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one is stuck in this situation here is the solution that worked for me.

As i am working on .Net Application i created the bundles of data tables js and css. When i try to include the css using bundles the files were not getting included when the page was rendering. ( Came to know from firebug networks tab ). I tried to include the file in a traditional way on aspx page and it worked perfectly.

Not sure why bundle thing not working for me.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks